# android action_shutdown ensure code execution

Tags: android, boot

I need to execute some code when the device turns off so I use a broadcast receiver to handle that situation in this way:

```
@Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{        

   if("android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN".equals(intent.getAction()) || "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWEROFF".equals(intent.getAction()))
   {  Do my logout staff here;
      return;
   }
}
```

Of course I add the corresponding permission in the Manifest. In fact it works sometimes, but other times the device gets powered off before my code has finished. Is there a way to tell the device to wait a few more seconds before switching off completely?

What I do exactly is to call a WebService and tell there that this device is OFF so I need Internet and the enough time to send the Soap command.
Thanks

Comment: I do not think this freedom is at all possible(unless your device is rooted). However as a work arround, you can try to implement it in vice-versa. I mean, you can send the I_AM_ACTIVE status to your servers after every n mins.

Comment: I guess that is an idea ;-)